# When a string is being matched against a regular expression, what's going on behind the scenes?

Tags: regex

I'd be interested to know what kind of algorithms are used for matching it, and how they are optimised, because I imagine that somes regexes could produce a vast number of possible matches that could cause serious problems on a poorly witten regex parser.

Also, I recently discovered the concept of a [ReDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redos), why do regexes such as `(a|aa)+` or `(a|a?)+` cause problems?

EDIT: I have used them most in C# and Python, so that's what was in my mind when I was considering the question. I assume Python's is written in C like the rest of the interpreter, but I have no idea about C#

Comment: Those regexes are slow because they have to resort to backtracking AFAIK

Comment: Can you add some more tags? Which programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Please don't post shortened URLs unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sorry, Chrome extension did it automatically.

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked explains exactly why those particular regex are problematic, in the very section in which they are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of regular expression engine: NFA and DFA. I am quite rusty so I don't dare go into specifics by memory. [Here is a page](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) that goes through the algorithms, though. Some parsers will perform better with poorly-written expressions. A good book on the subject (that is sitting on my shelf) is [Mastering Regular Expression](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570).

Comment: That's a really interesting read, cheers. Exactly the kind of thing I was thinking about.

Comment: Actually, any finite automaton will have no problems with any Regex. The problem is the recursive backtracking in almost any engine since Perl to acommodate for the more advanced features (mostly backreferences). The article you linked to specifically explains that, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I find http://www.regular-expressions.info has really useful info about regular expressions.

The author specifically talks about [catastrophic uses of regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 1):

Regex Buddy has this debug page which "offers you a unique view inside a regular expression engine".

http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html

Comment: I forgot about Regex Buddy, it is a **really** neat program.